# Running sendgrid script works manually but fails when run under crontab

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron, sendgrid

My aim is to send a pdf file, created through an R script, to multiple stakeholders using the `sendgrid` python package every week. When running the R script and the python mailing script manually, the mail and the attachment get sent successfully. But when I run them under a cron job, the mail fails to be sent

The pdf file that is created is `test.pdf`

The R script's location is

```
/home/username/script.R
```

And the python script's location is

```
/home/username/run.py
```

The content of `run.py` is as follows

```
import base64
import os
import json
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import (
  Mail, Attachment, FileContent, FileName,
  FileType, Disposition, ContentId)
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail

message = Mail(
  from_email='from_email@gmail.com',
  to_emails=['to_email1@gmail.com','to_email_2@gmail.com','to_email_3@gmail.com','to_email_4@gmail.com'],
  subject='Mail',
  html_content='<strong>Please find attached</strong>')
file_path = 'test.pdf'
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
  data = f.read()
f.close()
encoded = base64.b64encode(data).decode()
attachment = Attachment()
attachment.file_content = FileContent(encoded)
attachment.file_type = FileType('application/pdf')
attachment.file_name = FileName('test_filename.pdf')
attachment.disposition = Disposition('attachment')
attachment.content_id = ContentId('Example Content ID')
message.attachment = attachment
try:
  sendgrid_client = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
  response = sendgrid_client.send(message)
  print(response.status_code)
  print(response.body)
  print(response.headers)
except Exception as e:
  print(e.message)
```

Within crontab I have run the R and Python files the following way

```
0 8 * * 1  Rscript /home/username/script.R
10 8 * * 1 python /home/username/run.py
```

Upon looking at the cron logs using `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`, I see the following message

```
CRON[27260]: (username) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output but got status 0x0001 from MTA#012)
```

The Python script runs fine under manual conditions but fails when automated on cron. I have done the pre-requisite API authentications as per the `sendgrid` python package. Are there important settings that I have missed with respect to `crontab`? 
The OS is as follows

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, did you manage to resolve your problem? Because i am currently facing that same issue but with python :(